# How can I get unread messages for each user?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm creating a django web application. I want to create a one way messaging system so users can receive messages from admin. Currently I did this using a model like below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class AdminMessage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    receivers = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    message = models.TextField()
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

the problem is I want ***each*** user to be able to see his unread messages in his profile. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want each receiver to also have an unread state for the message, you will need a model for that:

```
class AdminMessageReceiver(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(AdminMessage)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

You can then hook this up as a [`through` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) on the many-to-many relationship:

```
class AdminMessage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    receivers = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=AdminMessageReceiver)
    message = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your solution and it almost worked but a couple of problems occurred. First is that in my admin page, I can't choose the receivers from "AdminMessage" section and the second is that even when I want to send a message from "AdminMessageReceiver" section, I can't choose multiple users because the relationship between two models are defined as ForeignKey.